# Short Story About Population Control Gone Horribly Wrong

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to locate a short story I read 30 years ago about a public relations guy who is hired to help the government develop a program to reduce the population. He comes up with several ideas promoting sterility, suicide, etc. but the program works a little too well & things spiral out of control with mass suicides, death-cults & the like.  In the end he's left with the last group of people on earth who are counting on him to mate with the last females to repopulate the earth.  I remember the last line of the story was:

> "I don't have the heart to tell them I'm sterile".

I also remember that the President of the USA now dresses up like Uncle Sam.

Comment: Hmm. Makes me think of a story (I THINK by Fredric Brown) involving a screw up where an advertiser (Funeral Home, or Coffin sales, or something similar) got too big of a budget (like via a transposed decimal), and was **too** successful advertising coffins.  Ends with an old man come down from the mountains, seeing the results, and looking at his mule, with a comment to the effect of 'Guess we have to try again.. Hope they don't favor your side of the family as much, next time.'  Not your story, tho.

Comment: Read this and immediately thought JG Ballard for some reason.  But it's definitely *not* one of his 2 shorts usually cited in lists of overpopulation fiction (Billenium and Concentration City).

Comment: It's come to our attention that you may have created two accounts, please follow this [link](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for advice on merging them.

Answer (score 10):

It might be [Sales of a Deathman](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52306) by Robert Bloch

It can be read on [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v26n03_1968-02_modified#page/n47/mode/2up)

Excerpts:

> What to do with the population problem? Killing people's so messy — unless they'll help!

[...]

> We've got the posters up — everything from "Join the Marine Corpse" to
> "Uncle Sam DOESN'T Want You!" And there's a big publicity campaign for
> the development of Death Valley National Monument.

[...]

> The president put it right on  the line. (Funny thing, he really looks like Uncle Sam now, even without makeup).
>
> “We’re got to repopulate,” he said. “Start all over again from the beginning.” He looked at me.
>
> “You’re our only hope. You and the girl.”
>
> I nodded. So did she.
>
> So tonight they’re setting the two of us up in a living unit of our own. Regular honeymoon suite. From now on, it’s up to me.

The ending line is not the same, though:

> Too bad. I just don’t think I’m going to make it. I’ve come to the conclusion Thoreau was right. In times like these, one must seek the peaceful serenity
> of Walden Pond.

...

> I think I’ll go there tonight. And drown myself.

Comment: That's gotta be it! Although the ending is different from my recollection, the plot line & details of the story match exactly. Takes me waaaay back! Thanks so much! And here is a better link to the story: https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v26n03_1968-02_modified#page/n47/mode/2up

Comment: @stormn thank you, I updated the link

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a little like "The Marching Morons" by C.M. Kornbluth.  However, the solution in TMM was to get everyone to visit another planet (Venus?).

Comment: Sounds like an appropriate title.

Comment: This isn't "The Marching Morons". That story is about (the phrase "That story is about" means SPOILERS) a scammer from the past, not a PR person.