# Man testifies before senate committee. He invented super-powerful easily-made gun which will change society. He just released plans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Man testifies before senate committee.  He has invented super powerful gun that is easily made.  Can vaporize tanks and planes.  Makes governments obsolete. Turns out he released plans already, committee will be obsolete.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: See [Looking for story about man on televised trial, presents plans for laser gun](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35794/looking-for-story-about-man-on-televised-trial-presents-plans-for-laser-gun/35798).

Comment: Also [Short story about a doomsday device shown on TVclassic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193646/short-story-about-a-doomsday-device-shown-on-tvclassic).

Comment: And [Book about a new laser rifle built by a new inventor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215262/book-about-a-new-laser-rifle-built-by-a-new-inventor).

Comment: I thought that the title of this story was "Sales of a Deathman", but that must be a different story.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30949/short-story-about-population-control-gone-horribly-wrong/212458

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. Don't imply the question - just ask it directly.

Answer (score 30):

Frank Herbert's short story "[Committee Of The Whole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_of_the_Whole_(short_story))". To quote the TV Tropes entry for [Can't Stop the Signal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CantStopTheSignal):

> A man uses the broadcast of a U.S. Senate hearing to describe a cheap, easily-built laser that could cut the Earth in half like a ripe tomato. He then spends several pages trying to justify distributing information that could allow any madman to destroy the planet. He later admits he had distributed the information far and wide earlier.

As pointed out by DavidW, The [April 1965 issue of *Galaxy Magazine*](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n04_1965-04/page/n6/mode/1up), containing this story, is available at the Internet Archive.

Comment: The April 1965 issue of *Galaxy Magazine* is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n04_1965-04/page/n6/mode/1up) (link to first page of story).

Comment: Back when laser were new, exciting, misunderstood and thus ripe for fiction.  Kinda like nanotechnology was 10-15 years ago, and networking was 20-25 years ago.

Comment: @RonJohn I'd argue that neither of your latter two examples are great examples. The implausible part of _War Games_ was the AI, not the networking; and grey goo – while not *that* scary if you flamethrower it all _early_ – could still be dangerous within the bounds of real physics. They're both unlike, say, slow pew-pew space lasers that explode planets.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 *War Games*?  No... more like cyberpunk.  And not *grey goo* either.  More like Star Gate replicators.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The problem with grey goo is that "early" can become "too late" *really quickly*.

Comment: @Shadur Only if it gets underground, or starts using tools (which requires something much more sophisticated than classic grey goo, which is getting more into soft sci-fi territory) or gets blown about by the wind.